# Page auto redirects to cart after filling onepage shipping address and click on next

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

During one page checkout, after filling the shipping address and click upon next button page again redirects to cart page?

No errors are displaying and my log file also empty.

On `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php` file inside the method `saveShippingAction()` I can see `$this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()`. This causes the error.

To find the error on root folder `index.php` I changed the below line

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

into

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

now on console I found below issue,

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Can't use method return value in write context in <b>/magento/htdocs/app/design
/frontend/default/default/template/deliverydate/shipping_method/available.phtml</b> on line <b>67</b
><br />
```

on available.phtml line no 67 I can find below:

```
<?php if(!empty($_rate->getMethodDescription())):?>
        <p class="address-block hide">
            <?php echo $_rate->getMethodDescription(); ?>
        </p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Note: The same is working fine on my local server, I faced this issue on production server only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP **empty** function, prior to PHP 5.5.0 only accepts variables as parameters; see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php. Are you running different PHP versions on your local vs production?

Comment: Yes, on my local php version is 5.5.12 and server version is 5.4.43. what do you mean by variables as parameters? You mean I have to assign into variable $_rate->getMethodDescription() and pass the variable into !empty()?

Comment: Yes I understood. Other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context gives more clarity for your point. Got it.